# Не работает калькулятор питон 3.7

Tags: python, калькулятор

```
print("Введите первое число:")

a = input ()
print ("Введите второе число")

b = input ()

print("Введите действие +/-")

f = input ()

if ("+"):

c = a + b
```

Почему все время в конце выводится 2 числа например
a = 1
b = 2
c почему то получится 12

Comment: Потому что надо привести строки к числам

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы складываете строки поэтому так получается. Чтобы ввод был числовым попробуйте так:

```
a=int(input())
```

Так в переменной а будет лежать число, а не строка.
Также можно переменной а присвоить переменную а-число:

```
а=int(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

`1 + 2 == 3` (число + число), но `"1" + "2" == "12"` (строка + строка).

Вы наверно хотели сделать это

```
a = int(input("Введите первое число: "))
b = int(input("Введите второе число: "))

f = input("Введите действие (+ или -): ")

if f == "+":
    c = a + b
elif f == "-":
    c = a - b

if f in ("+", "-"):    
    print(f"{a} {f} {b} = {c}")
else:
    print("Неправильное действие!")
```

---

*Примечания:*

1. `input()` всегда возвращает *строку*, потому нужно применить ещё функцию `int()` (или — для десятичных чисел - `float()`).
2. Не надо использовать `print()` с вопросом и затем `input()` без параметра, возможно вопрос добавить прямо в `input()` как параметр.
3. Вместо `if ("+"):` было нужно применить `if f == "+":`.
4. `f"{a} {f} {b} = {c}"` так называемая *f-строка* (c буквой `f` непосредственно перед открывающей кавычкой), где вместо выражений в фигурных скобках автоматически подставится их значение.